# line 35 else: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: django, django-views

i want to solve problem

---

- line 35
  else:
  ^ IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

---

```
else:
                    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                        #email is taken
                        pass
                    else:
                        patt = "^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$"
                        if re.match(patt, email):
                            user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=fname,
                            last_name=lname, email=email, username=username,
                            password=password)
                            user.save()
```

[image]

Comment: Which `if` is that `else` supposed to go with?  Indentation is the *only* mechanism Python has for associating them - and the indentation of the `else` doesn't match anything elsewhere in your code.  (Your editor is helpfully showing you vertical lines to help you line things up, pay attention to them!)

Answer (score 1):

Check the intendation for line 31 and 32 and 45 (looks like 3 whitespaces not 4). Pay attention for vertical lines.